# Updating R, R packages best practices

Tags: r, workflow, updating

What are best practices to updating R and packages, when you have a stable programming environment, to avoid "breaking" code/package functionality?

Should you download a new update of R or package when it's out? Or is a "if it isn't broken don't fix it" mentality preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: I like @Sirius's answer, but this is likely to be opinion-based ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your programming environment, update unless you have good reason not to, and maintain a good test suite for your in-house code. For projects with special needs, use `renv` to control versions of packages.

For your production environment, use the `renv` package to keep package versions locked down, and upgrade in a controlled manner if there is an explicit need.

Comment: Thanks Sirius. Appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

CRAN goes to great lengths to ensure that *all* current packages work with all other current packages under the current version of R.

So I tend to

- update to new R versions as soon as theu becomes available
- update CRAN packages (using a [helper script](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/update.r)) daily or near daily.

That has worked for more than two decades, including "in production". I have not needed `renv` but, as they say, *different strokes for different folks*.  I also stay away from packages I suspect may break, and try not to install "random" github snapshots.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, good to hear other's opinions.